# Why wrong proof accepted in Zokerates?

Tags: solidity, remix, privacy, zksnark

I'm trying to test a very simple example in Zokrates. so I used the very first example in the documentation, which is:

```
// This is an example from https://zokrates.github.io/gettingstarted.html
def main(private field a, field b) -> (field):
field result = if a * a == b then 1 else 0 fi
return result
```

And after deployment of verifier smart contract, I tried to test different number for proofing that. for example, a=2 and b=4 and I get this message **0:bool: r true** correctly.

But the problem is, I get the same response for any wrong proof same as correct proofs. For example a=3 and b=19 I get  **0:bool: r true** again.

why wrong proofs have a true response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generate a proof in ZoKrates, it is always valid. You might be confusing the program returning 0/1 and the proof being valid/invalid. You can invalidate the proof by fiddling with it (changing the `proof` points or elements in the `inputs` field).

Let me give you an example:

If you compute a witness for the program with arguments `a = 2` and `b = 4`, the output would be `1`. When you generate a proof using the computed witness, you get something like this:

```
{
  "proof": {
    "a": [
      "0x11ceea6848d6f4bb17fbe01e2f37a7f50aa5ea4da8aa6e4e364c3202dbb35deb",
      "0x04991e94bc0ae3718a464aecd3c351cadb9c779d8acf9601ac87245b7a5cec76"
    ],
    "b": [
      [
        "0x099a674ea974d7421b96a617635ac38939775ce47916487edaf5d384ddd401bf",
        "0x18b754e9665ee861740aa1ccb4def4ed4eb945d0f26be1dced2656004ea59111"
      ],
      [
        "0x022b35cca41f73cee44819184e9c0054e1553f3a31310e53581d90e526c93073",
        "0x22450d6b21830786c87e94131fbaaf9f6eaa93e6d526a827b42b706bee7654ff"
      ]
    ],
    "c": [
      "0x07405e6618cd88e94e44ceeade27f44d9dc362cf8f4de882b0d8905906d3daea",
      "0x1c8e8f412dfab3243f232fa9da9b1705bf99b05952819160d69c64ede0794fab"
    ]
  },
  "inputs": [
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
  ]
}
```

If you examine the `inputs` field in the proof, it contains the public parameters of the program (in this case the value of `b` which was `4`) and the output of the program (which was `1`).

If you verify this proof, the contract would return `{ "0": "bool: r true" }`. If you were to change something in the proof eg. change the first element in the `inputs` array to be `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003` and run the verification again, the proof would be invalid and therefore the verifier output would be `{ "0": "bool: r false" }`. You can also try changing the values in `a`, `b` or `c` groups, this would make the proof invalid as well.

In other words, passing the inputs in the computation step that will make the program result in a `0` would still generate a valid proof, because in that case you are verifying that the program resulted in a `0`.